Are questions about quant finance packages in scope?
For example, I believe I have found a discrepancy in fPortfolio - a packaged widely used for constructing optimal portfolios. I find that in the simple case of calculating portfolio weights for a global minimum variance portfolio, fPortfolio has a different result than an analytic matrix algebra procedure. I'd like to point out the issue on the exchange and see if there is some way to reconcile the discrepancy.

That's definitely in scope since it's a specific problem that a quant faces. Ask away!
